# Image upload to aws s3 bucket after resizing with graphicMagic

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, gm

I am using graphicMagic to resize an image before uploading it to aws s3 bucket. The code below uploads an image with 0 byte size, though the response from s3 upload is fine. The following code is what I am doing. The path is the path of the image that needs to be uploaded. The key is the hashed key to make the file name unique.

```
gm(path)
  .resize(100,100)
  .stream(function(err, stdout, stderr){
      if(err){
              console.log("Error resizing image. Message:",err);
      }
      else{
          console.log(stdout);
          var data = {
              Bucket: 'my-bucket',
              Key: key+"_thumb.jpg",
              Body: stdout,
              ACL: "public-read",
              ContentType:"image/jpeg"
          };
          p1 = s3.upload(data).promise();
      }
  });
```

I think stdout is not the correct thing to do, but then how do I make it work.

Comment: `stdout` is actually a `stream`, you're doing it correct, check my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is fine, you're missing `gm` dependencies: `imagemagick` or `graphicsmagick`, if one of those are missing, no error will be triggered, but you will get a 0 byte file.

Depending on your OS:

**Ubuntu/Debian**

```
sudo apt-get install graphicsmagick
# or
sudo apt-get install imagemagick
```

**Mac OS**

```
brew install graphicsmagick
brew install imagemagick
```

For windows or other OS, check:

- [GraphicsMagick](http://www.graphicsmagick.org/)
- [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php).